# How to get item text value inside a datalist in asp through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using a datalist in asp

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyField="CropID" DataSourceID="InformationList" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    ID:
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  class="badge badge-info" onClick="myFunc()" style="cursor: pointer;" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                    <asp:Label ID="ValueLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' style="visibility:hidden;" />
                    <br />
     
                    
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            </asp:DataList>
```

Im using this JS code

```
function myFunc() {
            alert("functioncalled");
            var someVariable = document.getElementById("<%=HyperLink1.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
            alert(someVariable);

        }
```

But an error comes HyperLink1 not in the current context

The List will come as

```
1
2
3
4
```

What i want is to get the specific value when clicked

If 1 is clicked 1 should be alerted
If 2 is clicked 2 should be alerted

Answer (score 0):

```
you can assing a varible a myFunc() function. etc myFunc(<%# Eval("ID") %>)  

<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  class="badge badge-info" onClick="myFunc()" style="cursor: pointer;" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>

    //later use this varible in functions
function myFunc(id) {
            alert("clicked" + id);
            /*var someVariable = document.getElementById("<%=HyperLink1.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
            alert(someVariable);*/

        }
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more please

Comment: you assign a value with onclick function.
Later you can use this value in MyFunc function.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try but it can work.

```
function tip(HyperLinkValue) {
  alert(HyperLinkValue);
}
```

Try send your parameter with func.

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  class="badge badge-info" onClick="myFunc(<%= Eval("ID") %>)" style="cursor: pointer;" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```